# Delete all jobs in the terminal

Tags: jobs, job-scheduling

I've created some jobs and I want to delete all the jobs together. Please, help me to delete all the jobs without using pid or job id. I want to delete all together not individual.

What I've tried:

[image: terminal]

Please, help me to delete all jobs.

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
work while(true); do kill -9 % ; done
```

this will help.